# Selenium message-error and message-success in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm facing a problem with finding an element that does not exist. When I try to login into the application, if it failed login it will show the element -

```
dr.findElement(By.className("message-error ")).getText();
```

And after a successful login it will show this:

```
dr.findElement(By.className("message-success")).getText();
```

When I run the code and it doesn't find the element, then execution stops with the exception: `element is not found`

```
String mes=null;        

mes=dr.findElement(By.className("message-success")).getText();
if(mes!=null) {
    File out= new File("success.txt");
    FileWriter fr =new FileWriter(out,true);
    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(fr);
    pw.println(mes+"|"+user.get(i)+"|"+pass.get(i));
    pw.close();
}
```

---

```
    mes=dr.findElement(By.className("message-error")).getText();
    if(mes!=null) {
        File out= new File("error.txt");
        FileWriter fr =new FileWriter(out,true);
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(fr);
        pw.println(mes+"|"+user.get(i)+"|"+pass.get(i));
        pw.close();
    }
```

The element does not appear.

For example, the success element will not shown until it is successful and the error element will not appear in the CSS until it gets an error.

So how can I tell it if element should exit or come to live or appear do an action?

What is the right thing to do in an if statement if the login is successful? Do this and login fail do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use WebdriverWait to wait for the visibility of success message,

```
 // After  valid login 
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
  WebElement successmessage wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("message-success")));
  sucessmessage.getText();
```

Similarly for error message,

```
// After  invalid login
 WebElement errormessage wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("message-error")));
 errormessage.getText();
```

Comment: the things is the program stop when there is an error want to use it in if statement if it right like if the successes paper do this else do the error thing

Comment: Are u testing or scrapping?

Answer (score 0):

What i think is you have same element but the class getting change as per application behavior. suppose if you are able to login in the application then it show the message element with class having attribute `message-success` and if it won't allow then error message with class having attribute 'message-error' in the same element.

I've handled the same in below code -

```
// first get the message element with some other locator or other attribute (don't use class name)

WebElement message = driver.findElement(By.locator);

if(message.getAttribute("class").contains("message-success")){

    System.out.println("Success message is " + message.getText())        
    // write the code to perform further action you want on login success

}else if (message.getAttribute("class").contains("message-error")){

    System.out.println("Error message is " + message.getText())  
    // write the code to perform further action you want on login Fail

}else{

    System.out.println("Message is empty" + message.getText())
}
```

Let me know if you have further queries.

Answer (score 0):

My Choice is to use Webdriver wait. it is the perfect way to find an element.

```
    public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver,15)
    WebElement successmessage = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfallElementLocatedby(By.className("message-success")));
   sucessmessage.getText();
```

**visibilityOfallElementLocatedby :**

An expectation for checking that all elements present on the web page that match the locator are visible. Visibility means that the elements are not only displayed but also have a height and width that is greater than 0.

The above i wrote is for success Message, similar way try for invalid login.

To use different types of wait, check this doc - https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/allclasses-noframe.html

search Wait in that document.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer for the question it work with me

```
    try {
    WebElement sucmes=dr.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='message']"));
    String suclogin="login success:";
    if(sucmes.getText().contains(suclogin)) {
    File suclogin= new File("suclog.txt");
                FileWriter suclogr =new FileWriter(suclogin,true);
                PrintWriter suclogrw=new PrintWriter(suclogr);
                suclogrw.println(sucmes.getText());
                suclogrw.close();
            }else{
//the other action here 
}
    }
```